# Convergence in probability in the setting of free probability

Tags: pr.probability, limits-and-convergence, free-probability

Let $A_n$ and $B_n$ be sequences of positive-definite random matrices whose empirical spectral distributions converge to (possibly different) limiting spectral distributions $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$. Assume that $A_n$ and $B_n$ are asymptotically free, in the sense of free probability. One may assume that both $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ have compactly supported spectra.

I am interested in studying the *convergence in probability* of quantities like $\frac1n\operatorname{tr}\left(( I + A_n + B_n)^{-1}\right)$ and $\frac1n\operatorname{tr}\left((A_nB_n+I)^{-1}\right)$.

I know very little about free probability theory except that it may be the only tool available to me since I am not in a setting where I can use the CLT. However, convergence results in the free probability literature always seem to be given in terms of convergence in distribution, at least in my perusal of the literature. I need something a bit stronger.

**Does the framework of free probability allow me to characterize the convergence in probability of such quantities?**

[Edited to avoid the obstruction mentioned in the comments.]

Comment: You need a bit more. For example, concerning your first question, you need to make sure that the lowest eigenvalue of $A_n+B_n$ is not too small. Asymptotical freeness will not help in checking that, as bounded rank 2 perturbations of both $A_n$ and $B_n$ will not affect their asymptotic freeness but can be chosen so that the lowest eigenvalue of $A_n+B_n$ is 0.

Comment: I have edited the question to avoid the obstruction. In fact in the case I care about there is always an identity term that prevents the total sum $I_n + A_n + B_n$ from having an eigenvalue near zero. Even under stronger assumptions than I have stated I would love to know if there are any results in the free probability literature that give convergence in probability to some limiting distribution.

Comment: Often one has almost sure convergence (and asymptotic freeness) in free probability. In order to avoid problems with taking the inverse one should have strong convergence - then one can also control rational functions of the involved matrices; see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.07250.pdf

Comment: With your edit, you are fine, at least for the first functional, as it is a continuous function of the empirical measure.  Free probability gives you in particular the weak convergence, in probability, of the empirical measure.